# Could not run installed asdf plugins (elixir/node) even if the plugins has been installed

Tags: bash, elixir, asdf

I've installed asdf successfully and I could install the plugin with asdf. but when it is time to run the plugin, the plugin itself is unavailable from the terminal even though the asdf list told me that the plugin (package) is in there (installed).

```
ubuntu@767c4736d92a:/app$ asdf list
elixir
  1.14.3-otp-25
erlang
  25.2.2
nodejs
 *16.17.0
postgres
 *15.1
ubuntu@767c4736d92a:/app$ elixir
bash: elixir: command not found
ubuntu@767c4736d92a:/app$ npm
bash: npm: command not found
ubuntu@767c4736d92a:/app$ node
bash: node: command not found
ubuntu@767c4736d92a:/app$
```

Comment: Reload the `.bashrc` file (just start the new shell.)

Comment: Open in a new terminal and the issue should no longer persist

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the shell doesn't know where to find the plugins that you have installed through asdf, that is why it is not letting you be able to run the commands of the plugins that you have installed.

You can resolve this issue by adding the asdf shims directory to your shells PATH environment variable.

The command to add the directory to PATH can be looked up on Google.